# How to remove a piece of text from a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to remove a piece of text (Perfomance) from a column in Google Spreadsheet that contains (XX Performance) XX is a number like 89. I'm using:

=REGEXREPLACE(D:D, " Performance "," - ")

But no love...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD3ml.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this** [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11nW6scPz9z6egy2Dp-b0854kOSUSJsGkoTl41vDn_2Y/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D="",, REGEXEXTRACT(D2:D, "[0-9]+")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Osm, thanks for the answer. Actually, I modified my post a little as I try to apply this to the whole D column. Can it be done in the same column or you have to put the results in a new one?

Comment: It is in all the D column just paste it and enjoy

Comment: Did it and get this error: https://i.ibb.co/DMvxf1C/Screenshot-2022-08-04-at-11-29-45.png (Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A2.
)

Comment: Remove the cell below thy have values or formulas

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression `\D+`:

- `\D` matches any character that's not a digit (equivalent to [^0-9])
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

The formula will be like:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D:D, "\D+","")
```

**UPDATE**

> I did put it in another column otherwise it creates a circular dependency. The data is imported via API from another app.

Then you will need to create another sheet or use a hidden column to put that information and then use the regex on the column you want the final result.

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't change anything

https://i.ibb.co/Z1dQvL3/Screenshot-2022-08-04-at-11-22-31.png

Comment: Can you try it in another column? Also how is the text inserted in the cell?

Comment: I did put it in another column otherwise it creates a circular dependency. The data is imported via API from another app.